# problems with allocation an array with main argoment type

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-allocation

im supposed to create a main with argoment as 
"int main(int argc,char* argve[])" 
first one is the type(can be "int/long/char") of an array and seconed is the size, and i need to allocate the array based on the choosen type
i got the size with atoi function easlly 
but cant figured it out how to get the type into the correct pointer of choosen type
i simplly dont understand how this casting work and how to cast it for each type correctly,
any explanation of how to do it right?

thats what i got so far

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int size = atoi(argv[2]);


    if (strcmp(argv[1], "int") == 0)
    {
        int* arr = nullptr;
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "long") == 0)
    {
        long* arr = nullptr;
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "char") == 0)
    {
        char* arr = nullptr;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have no cast! Are you supposed to define `void* arr`? This is a verry bad assignment. YAIT (yet another incompetent teachert)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new function with a `template` and call it from `main`:

```
template <class T>
int realmain(int size)
{
    T *arr = new T[size];
    //whatever you want to do

    delete []arr;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int size = atoi(argv[2]);


    if (strcmp(argv[1], "int") == 0)
    {
        return realmain<int>(size);
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "long") == 0)
    {
        return realmain<long>(size);
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "char") == 0)
    {
        return realmain<char>(size);
    }
}
```

Comment: but how do i get the array to the main agian?

Comment: You do not have to, whatever you want to do in `main`, do it in `realmain` (you can choose a better name depending on the task).

Comment: i understand your solution but i need to get the arr in the main it self and keep work with it on other functions

Answer (score 0):

It works because of *scoping* of the variables. Your 3 `arr` variables are block scoped in 3 distinct blocks, so even if they share the same name, the compilers sees them as 3 different variables, so it feels fine them to be of different types.

That being said, it would not be good practice in real world code, because is adds unnecessary complexity for a human reader.